# how to port Android on beagle board with GPS?

Tags: android, beagleboard

I have a beagle board, i have ported android on it.Now i want to integrate GPS with it.Are there any solutions available? if not how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed a driver for your GPS? I would compile a GPS driver for beagleboard and test it out on the test board. modprobe and rmmod work well on Android if you have root access.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the GPS modules available in the market are based on RS232/UART. Beagleboard does support UART interfaces through an RS232 Cape. You should be able to get open source code for GPS drivers when the protocol is UART.